# sidebar navigation problem with child pages not all display.?

Tags: menus

Corsetería  is parant pages and 25 sub pages.
but display only 17 pages
[image]

Comment: I don't know of a specific limit, but if you have a lot of pages I have either had to page through them - i.e. if you scroll down there may be (1 2 3 4 ->) pagination so you need to go to the next page - or else it may be easier to search for the specific page instead.

Comment: @WebElaine thanks you reponse give answer i accept this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a specific limit, but if you have a lot of pages I have either had to page through them - i.e. if you scroll down there may be (1 2 3 4 ->) pagination so you need to go to the next page - or else it may be easier to search for the specific page instead.